# Styling with CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

All the project gets affected by changes I make in any CSS file even if it's not imported to that file.
for example: If I created a file called `test1.js` and imported a file called `test.css` inside of it then created a new file called `test2.js` and gave the same classes to its components they get styled the same way as `test1.js` even without importing the CSS file into it.

How can I get around this problem? is using SASS away to avoid it?

Can you please recommend the best practice for styling in react?

Comment: Without posting your code it's hard to answer in a way that's specific to you. Know that when you import a css file into react the classes themselves get imported, but aren't usually scoped to be specific to only the file they are imported in. Example: if you import the class `test-class` into any file and in both `test2.js` and `test2.js` you use that class, it will be available to both. CSS Modules is a way to scope classes locally to the file. [webpack CSS modules documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules)

Comment: As Mike said above, it's hard to say without code. I personally use styled-components (https://styled-components.com/) for my CSS as it is geared towards components and is fantastic!